# Pass in logical operators (and partial expressions) into a function argument Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, logical-operators

In SQLAlchemy, it is possible to do something like this:

```
mytable.query.filter(mytable.some_col < 5).all()
```

How can I implement something similar? I want developer users to be able to pass in logical operations to a function. Here's an example:

```
class row_obj:
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val1)+","+str(self.val2)+","+str(self.val3)+","+str(self.val4)

class table_obj:
    """ takes a list of row_objs """
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows #rows is a list of row_obj 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join([str(row) for row in self.rows])
    def filter(self, condition):
        # I would like to return all rows which meet the condition here
        return table_obj([row for row in self.rows if condition])

a = table_obj([ row_obj(1,2,3,4),
      row_obj(5,6,7,8),
      row_obj(2,4,6,8),
      row_obj(5,2,7,4)])

print a.filter(row_obj.val3 == 7)
#should return 
#5,6,7,8
#5,2,7,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately this is somewhat non trivial, and kind of gross to implement but you can do something like this

```
import operator
class Comparator:
     def __init__(self,fieldName,compareToValue,my_operator):
         self.op = my_operator
         self.field = fieldName
         self.comparedTo = compareToValue
     def __call__(self,row):
         my_row_val = getattr(row,self.field)
         return self.op(my_row_val,self.comparedTo)
class row_obj:
    class RowItem:
         def __init__(self,name):
              self.name = name
         def __eq__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.eq)
    val1 = RowItem("val1")
    val2 = RowItem("val2")
    val3 = RowItem("val3")
    val4 = RowItem("val4")

    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.val1,self.val2,self.val3,self.val4])
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class MyTable:
    def __init__(self,rows):
        self.rows = rows
    def filter(self,condition):
        for row in self.rows:
            if condition(row):
               yield row

rows = [row_obj(1,2,3,4),row_obj(1,2,7,4),row_obj(1,2,3,4),row_obj(7,7,7,7)]
mytable = MyTable(rows)
print list(mytable.filter(row_obj.val3 == 7))
```

this is more to just give you an idea of the path you will have to take which will be non-trivial (and kind of gross...)

Comment: This works, but why wouldn't this work:
`print list(mytable.filter(row_obj.val3 == 7 or True))`

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, SQLAlchemy allows expressions like:

```
mytable.query.filter(mytable.some_col < 5).all()
```

This is possible because `mytable.some_col` implements magic methods for each logical operator which returns some other object (in this case `__lt__`). So the operator is not really passed in. In my application, which defines a `User` object, this can be seen via:

```
>>> User.first_name == 'John'
<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x10f0991d0>
```

You could do the same to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass lambda functions to do this; they are then just processed as any normal function:

```
>>> def someFunction (condition):
        return [row for row in range(100) if condition(row)]
>>> someFunction(lambda x: x % 11 == 0)
[0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
>>> someFunction(lambda x: x % 23 == 0)
[0, 23, 46, 69, 92]
```

And of course, instead of passing a simple int object as in my example, you can also pass a more complex object and do some more complex checks on it, e.g.:

```
lambda x: x.someOtherProperty.evenAMethod('with a parameter') > 42
```

---

For the concrete example in your question: Change `table_obj.filter` to call the `condition` parameter with the row as its argument:

```
def filter(self, condition):
    return table_obj([row for row in self.rows if condition(row)])
    #                                                      ^^^^^
    #                                                     new part
```

And then, you can use a lambda expression to specify your filter:

```
 print a.filter(lambda row_obj: row_obj.val3 == 7)
 #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 #                 new part
```

That gives you *exactly* the desired result.

Comment: This is not addressing the question - sorry if it wasn't clear, but I want to reference specific columns for an object like the ones defined above.

Comment: @mgoldwasser Yes, it is addressing the question very well. See my edit on how to transfer the concept to your exact example.